# Erlang: How to "Do Nothing" in true branch of if statement

Tags: if-statement, erlang

I have this `if` statement:

```erlang
if 
    A /= B -> ok;
    true   ->
end.
```

I want it to do nothing when `A == B`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Erlang does not have the notion of `nothing` like `void` or `unit`. I would suggest returning another atom like `not_ok` (or even `void` or `unit`.)

Comment: Yes, everything always returns a value. You cannot not return a value.

Comment: unless you throw an exception and don't handle it

Comment: i don't want any atom in return.
i just need an operation to be done only when the first condition is true.

Comment: Atoms do nothing, so the answer for your current question is correct. You are solving different problem than you asked. Show us real code and you'll get desired answer.

Comment: @itamar As must I have said you will always get a return value! It is a functional language and everything is an expression which returns a value. Even if you do something just for its side-effect it will still return a value. **YOU CANNOT NOT RETURN VALUE!**

Comment: @chops But that is a different functionality as you are not continuing afterwards. Unless of course if you do a `catch if ... end`, which is similar but again different.

Comment: @rvirding Absolutely, I was just being pedantic. You *can* choose to not return a value, but it also means the function itself doesn't return at all. But you are 100% right. Personally, I return the atom `do_nothing` when I want nothing to happen in a particular branch of a `case` or `if`

Answer (score 7):

The best answer is don't use if, just use case.

```
case A of
   B -> ok;
   C -> throw({error,a_doesnt_equal_b_or_whatever_you_want_to_do_now})
end
```

typically `ok` or `undefined` or `noop` are returned as atoms which mean essentially, nothing.

Comment: If you don't use the second branch, why don't use `case` and leave it out? `if` isn't very functional at all.

Comment: @ckruse You can't leave it out because `case`, the same as `if`, generates an error if none of the patterns match. Erlang doesn't have default return values, you always have to handle every case.

Answer (score 3):

As said, any code will return something.

If you want to do something only in one case, then you can write this:

```
ok =if 
    A /= B -> do_something(A,B); % note that in this case do_something must return ok
    true -> ok
end.
```

if you want to get new values for A, B you can write this

```
{NewA,NewB} = if 
    A /= B -> modify(A,B); % in this case modify returns a tuple of the form {NewA,NewB}
    true -> {A,B} % keep A and B unchanged 
end.
% in the following code use only {NewA,NewB}
```

or in a more "erlang way"

```
%in your code
...
ok = do_something_if_different(A,B),
{NewA,NewB} = modify_if_different(A,B),
...

% and the definition of functions
do_something_if_different(_A,_A) -> ok;
do_something_if_different(A,B) ->
    % your action
    ok.

modify_if_different(A,A) -> {A,A};
modify_if_different(A,B) ->
    % insert some code
    {NewA,NewB}.
```

last if you expect that it crashes if A == B

```
%in your code
...
ok = do_something_if_different_else_crash(A,B),
...


% and the definition of functions
do_something_if_different_else_crash(A,B) when A =/= B ->
    % your action
    ok.
```